# How to count unique views to a blog post (logged in and non logged in user)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

I want to display how many times a blog post has been read kind of like what Business Insider has.

The objective is...

- View count that doesn't increment with every reload.
- Every blog post stores its own view count
- Fetch the view count from MongoDB/Mongoose Schema field and display it in HTML.

  ```
  var express         = require('express');
  var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
  var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
  var express-session = require('express-session');

  //Show Blog Post 

  router.get('/blog/:categorySlug/:slug', function (req, res)
    var slug = req.params.slug;
      Blog.findOne({'slug' : slug}).populate('comments').exec(function (err, foundBlog) {
        if (err) {
      console.log(err);
        } else {
       res.render('show', { main: foundBlog, title: foundBlog.title});
      }
    });
  });
  ```

I know that if i use `req.session.views`, it will increment the view count with every reload across all pages.

```
router.get('/blog/:categorySlug/:slug', function (req, res) { 
  req.session.views = (req.session.views || 0) + 1  
  var slug = req.params.slug;
    Blog.findOne({'slug' : slug}).populate('comments').exec(function (err, foundBlog) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render('show', { main: foundBlog, title: foundBlog.title, pageViewCount: req.session.views});
      }
    });
  });
```

So what could i do to save the view count of each blog separately and store that view count value in that blog post's `viewCount` field in the database and then render it in HTML using `<%= main.viewCount %>`

```
    // Blog Schema

      var mainBlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      image: String,
      imageDescription: String,
      priority: {
         type: String,
         default: ""
      },
      title: String,
      content: String,
      author: {
         id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User',
       },
         username: String,
         name: String,
      },
      slug: {
         type: String,
         unique: true,
      },
      status: String,
      viewCount: {
         type: Number,
         default: 0,
      },
      category: String,
      categorySlug: String,
      tags: String,
      updated: {
         type: Boolean,
         default: false
      },
      date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      comments: [
        {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Comment',
        },
       ],
     },{
     timestamps: {
       createdAt: 'createdAt',
       updatedAt: 'updatedAt'
      }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be (might need changes)

> 1. Before the UI page loads, a script checks for user-token(separate token or some random string token)in the browser.
> 2. If token is not available then send request for new token along with page-id.
> 3. If token is available, call API with the token and page-id.
> 4. Make sure it gets called for every page load or even page transition.

Backend implementation can be like

> 1. Page collection will have page-id along with visits:[] field.
> 2. One API creates token and stores it in a separate collection(users) and follows step 3.
> 3. Another API will take the token and page-id as input, it will first. check the token is available in our collection(user) and if so it will do a mongo update on Page collection with

```
db.pages.update(
   { _id: page-id },
   { $addToSet: {visits: [ user_token ] } }
)
```

This query takes care if the token stored is unique no need to worry about anything. We can maintain a separate field called **visitCount** if needed, which gets updated with the latest count once query gets executed updating at least one record.

**Pros**

> 1. Page refresh will not affect the count.
> 2. The token is also maintained at our end so we can validate.

**Cons**

> 1. We will need huge space to store these token and we have to delete them if a user did not visit the site for a very long time.
> 2. API calls overhead.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will give it a try and if something i'll get back to you.

Comment: sure, do let me know @MichaelSanders

Comment: would you us something like JWT for token?

Comment: That can be anything a JWT or some random but unique string, it's just for identification.

Comment: Would you say it would be better to pass it as a middleware to my route above or post it in the route?

Comment: Also, when you say "user-token", are you implying i create a user profile for every visitor that comes to the page?

Comment: Make it in the route, but don't block the user if token is invalid, just don't increment the count and let him see the page anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166074/discussion-between-akhilesh-krishnan-and-michael-sanders).

Comment: @MichaelSanders please accept the answer if it helped you fix the issue, it might help others looking out for same issue