# How to count views in your nodejs blog

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, blogs

How do I count the views of my article(when user is not logged) in an efficient way.

The application uses nodejs with express and mongodb but any rough idea along with a few code samples would help me.

Constraints:

- I do not want to create and store tokens as demonstrated in an answer here [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020777/how-to-count-unique-views-to-a-blog-post-logged-in-and-non-logged-in-user-usin)
- I want it to work for unlogged users and not compromise on security by storing anything on client side(as its editable)

Maybe I can use **user's ip** as a starting point to identify each user(it's okay if it keeps changing in a few minutes)

I can only think of a way by storing user's ip/tokens inside the db to make this work but that would be very ineffiecient

Is anything other than that possible (like storing ip in some sort of local variable that does not change for a user and is secure)?

**EDIT**
I've found a quick trick that would reduce chances of duplicate views
We can update the no of views on a post when a user exits a page not before that. In this way he can refresh as many times(unintently) and still results can be somewhat accurate

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  //post request for incrementing view
}
```

Comment: I want something similar to SO's view count that is unique for each user(logged in) but also with a constraint that I do not need to store each user's id or something inside post collection

Comment: There are probably actually a literal million tutorials out there on visitor counters. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: @TylerH I don't have a difficulty in updating a simple views field on user's refresh. The problem lies in making it efficient. Maybe there are a million tutorials but none of them seem to address the issues I have pointed out i.e. preventing duplicates while still not compromising on security && reducing space complexity inside database.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? Just count how many times a page is requested by a server and increment each time it happens. There is also no security concern or complexity concern this way.

Comment: @TylerH A non-logged user can refresh a page as many times as it wants to increment his own views on his own blog. Think before you answer

Comment: @TylerH I can create a simple piece of code that calls a server a 1000 times (if there's no rate limiting in place)

Comment: "*A non-logged user can refresh a page as many times as it wants to increment his own views on his own blog.*" Congratulations, you just uncovered why view counters are 100% useless/vanity metrics. Think before you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your related code and some information on your database, I can only give some advice on an conceptual level:

### Easy but inaccurate

The most basic (and arguably the most inaccurate) solution would be to count each request for an article.

Whenever a request for your article is received by the server, it processes that request and also fires an insert into your database.

The main problems with that solution are:

- You can't tell whether the article was actually read (to be fair, that goes for most methods that don't track the user's time on a site, scrolling etc).
- A user may reload the page counting as another view.

### More complex but more accurate

The problems of the solution above could be partially negated by generating a random-id for each "user"(well actually device) and storing that to localStorage/cookies, a bit like the [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49020777/14998487) you have pointed out.

When they click on an article, the ID is sent in the request for the article and then insert the user-id & article combination in your database. That way, you can generate semi-accurate unique views and views per user.

Main problems here:

- You count per device not user.
- Needs cookie-consent (depending where the site is available)
- A user may delete cookies etc. and will be counted as a new user each time.
- If not careful, you end up with duplicate user-ids

Comment: Thanks for your advice but as I said earlier I don't want to store user tokens inside db. Because it is very inefficient and space consuming. Imagine having thousands of articles each with their own millions of user Id's. Can you think of anything else ?

Comment: Well without any way to distinguish viewers, pretty much all you can do is count the number of time an article has been requested. If you want to count unique viewers, you could also try to save flag in localStorage whether an article has been seen already⇾ you include that flags value in your request and update/don't update the view count accordingly. However, there isn't too much accuracy in that either.

Comment: yes that's what I pointed out there is no efficient way or secure way I can think of to count views. I am accepting your answer